# Layout width doesnt change when showing/hiding other UI elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager2

DISCLAIMER: This is part of a very large project, so I did what I can to simplify it.

I am in the process of making a walk through Wizard in Xamarin.Android. I am trying to make it as flexible as possible where I can start the wizard activity and it will return a result (StartActivityWithResult). The contents of the wizard is set by different view pager2 adapters and are an enum parameter of the Intent. To simplify the problem, I've removed this part and hard coded the Adapter types to one specific adapter that isn't working.

The wizard activity is very simple. It has a title (Toolbar), a view pager, and a bottom button. The bottom button can be either an icon or text. Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/stepsPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/BorderTopOrange"
            android:id="@+id/BottomButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle">
            <ImageView
                android:background="@color/sickGreen"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgBottomButtonDrawable"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <TextView
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:text="@string/ok"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/standardWhite"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/tvBottomButtonText" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

As the pages(step 1, step 2...etc) in the view pager2 change, I want to update the Title, Bottom Button Text/Icon, and OnClickEventHandler of the bottom button. So I created an interface called `IWizardStep`.

```
    public interface IWizardStep
        {
            public string Title { get; }
            public string BottomButtonText { get; }
            public int BottomButtonDrawableResource { get; }
            public void OnButtonClick();
        }
```

Each Fragment of the ViewPager2 will implement this interface.

```
public class WizardStep1 : BaseFragment, IWizardStep
    {
        public string Title => "First Step";

        public string BottomButtonText => "Test";

        public int BottomButtonDrawableResource => 0;

        public void OnButtonClick()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Context, "Success!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.wizard_step1, container, false);
        }

        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
        }
    }
```

To update the title and button text the WizardActivity registers a fragment lifecycle callback. In the lifecycle call back's OnResume override those UI elements are updated. Here is the call back implementation:

```
class WizardStepLifecycleCallback : FragmentLifecycleCallbacks
    {
        ILogger Logger;
        Action<string> action_ChangeTitle;
        Action<string, int> action_ChangeBottomButton;

        public WizardStepLifecycleCallback(ILogger logger, Action<string> changeTitle, Action<string, int> changeBottomButton)
        {
            Logger = logger;
            action_ChangeTitle = changeTitle;
            action_ChangeBottomButton = changeBottomButton;
        }

        public override void OnFragmentResumed(AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fm, AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment f)
        {
            base.OnFragmentResumed(fm, f);

            if (f is IWizardStep step)
            {
                Try(() => action_ChangeTitle.Invoke(step.Title));
                Try(() => action_ChangeBottomButton.Invoke(step.BottomButtonText, step.BottomButtonDrawableResource));
            }
        }

        private void Try(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Ignore exceptions
                Logger.Error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Tying it all together is the Wizard Activity:

```
[Activity(ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class WizardActivity : BaseActivity
    {
        private ViewPager2 _viewPager;
        private WizardAdapter _pagerAdapter;
        public TextView tvBottomButton;
        public ImageView imgBottomButton;
        private LinearLayout BottomButton;


        protected override int LayoutResource
        {
            get
            {
                return Resource.Layout.Wizard;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            tvBottomButton = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvBottomButtonText);
            imgBottomButton = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgBottomButtonDrawable);
            BottomButton = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.BottomButton);
            BottomButton.AddClickHandler(OnButtonClick);

            // Instantiate a ViewPager2 and a PagerAdapter.
            _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager2>(Resource.Id.stepsPager);
            _viewPager.UserInputEnabled = false;
            SupportFragmentManager.RegisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new WizardStepLifecycleCallback(Logger, UpdateTitle, UpdateBottomButton), false);

            _pagerAdapter = new WizardAdapter(this);
            _viewPager.Adapter = _pagerAdapter;


        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
        }

        private void OnButtonClick()
        {
            if (_viewPager.CurrentItem < SupportFragmentManager.Fragments.Count)
            {
                var frag = SupportFragmentManager.Fragments[_viewPager.CurrentItem];

                if (frag != null && frag is IWizardStep wizardStep)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        wizardStep?.OnButtonClick();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logger.Error(e);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTitle(string title)
        {
            EnsureRunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                Toolbar.Title = title ?? "";
            });
        }

        public void UpdateBottomButton(string buttonText, int drawableResource)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                if (drawableResource != 0)
                {
                    //Use Drawable
                    imgBottomButton.SetImageResource(drawableResource);
                    tvBottomButton.Visibility = ViewState.Gone;
                    imgBottomButton.Visibility = ViewState.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Use Text
                    tvBottomButton.Text = buttonText ?? "";
                    imgBottomButton.Visibility = ViewState.Gone;
                    tvBottomButton.Visibility = ViewState.Visible;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In `BaseActivity` this is how the layout is inflated:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(LayoutResource);
            ContentView = FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);

            Toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            if (Toolbar != null)
            {
                Toolbar.Title = string.Empty;

                SetSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
                SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

Finally, Here is the Wizard's View Pager2 Adapter:

```
public class WizardAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter
    {

        private enum Steps
        {
            Step1
        }

        public WizardAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) : base(fragmentActivity) { }

        override public int ItemCount => Enum.GetNames(typeof(Steps)).Length;

        override public Fragment CreateFragment(int position)
        {
            switch ((Steps)position)
            {
                case Steps.Step1:
                default:
                    return new WizardStep1();
            }
        }

    }
```

PROBLEM: The problem is on the first loading of the screen, the textview of the bottom button is not displayed, even though it is visible and the Text is correctly set (I did a debug and I can see the value of tvBottomButton.Text). Notice how the title is set correctly and If I click on the bottom button the Toast displays correctly. This is the output of the first visit to that screen:[See the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urd7v.png)

After I pause the app and resume it, it displays correctly. [See the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtzkN.png)

I've tried assigning weights to the `tvBottomButton` and `imgBottomButton`. I also tried assigning those weights at runtime depending on showing/hiding the elements, but similar result where I can see the TextView text correctly, but its weight is the original weight and is not a refreshed weight.[See Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igldC.png)

I also tried adding `.RequestLayout()` on the `BottomButton`, `tvBottomButton`, and `imgBottomButton`. As well as `.Invalidate()` on the `root view`, `tvBottomButton`, `BottomButton`, `imgBottomButton`. all from within the `UpdateBottomButton()` method, but the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I got it to work by surrounding the Update of the bottom button text in a post on the root view, rather than running it immediately:

```
public void UpdateBottomButton(string buttonText, int drawableResource)
    {
        EnsureRunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            RootView.Post(() =>
            {
                if (drawableResource != 0)
                {
                    //Use Drawable
                    BottomButtonImg.SetImageResource(drawableResource);
                    BottomButtonTV.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 0f);
                    BottomButtonImg.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 2f);
                    BottomButtonTV.Hide();
                    BottomButtonImg.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Use Text
                    BottomButtonTV.Text = buttonText ?? "";
                    BottomButtonImg.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 0f);
                    BottomButtonTV.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 2f);
                    BottomButtonImg.Hide();
                    BottomButtonTV.Show();
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you accept this as answer ? It is helpful to the people who faces the same issue.